# Do I seal just the grout lines or the whole granite tile surface area?

Tags: tile

i have just installed granite tiles in my entryway and was reading the sealer instructions . Do i just seal grout lines or the entire surface area?

Answer (score 3):

With natural stone I seal everything. With glazed tiles I usually only seal the grout lines because the tile glaze is a sealer so putting additional sealer won’t add protection and in some cases can change the color or surface shine of the tile.

So glazed and porcelain I do the grout lines natural stone I seal the stone & grout because both are porous.